# Preventing pre-mature shell parameter expansion in chained commands

Tags: bash, parameters, expansion

I have a system that allows commands to be executed from a host to various external machines, from a bash shell script using either ssh or 'sersh', which is similar to ssh but sends commands over a serial port. (The details of these commands don't matter.)

I'm trying to chain the commands together, from one external machine to
yet a 3rd machine. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get the shell to expand parameters only on the final machine.

```
function do_cmd () {
    case $TRANSPORT in
        ssh)
            ssh -i ${SSH_KEY} ${LOGIN}@${IPADDR} "$@"
            ;;
        serial)
            sersh ${SER_LOGIN}@{SERIAL_DEV} "$@"
            ;;
        ssh2serial)
            ssh -i ${SSH_KEY} ${LOGIN}@{IPADDR} \
               "sersh ${SER_LOGIN}@${SERIAL_DEV} $@"
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Unknown transport $TRANSPORT"
            ;;
    esac
}

do_cmd "echo hello"
do_cmd "echo \"my pid is \$\$\""
do_cmd "cd /proc ; for pid in 1* ; do echo \$pid, ; done"
```

All three of these calls work correctly when TRANSPORT is 'ssh' or 'serial'.  For the TRANSPORT 'ssh2serial', in the second call to do_cmd, the $$ is expanded prematurely (on the intermediate machine, not on the final machine).  And for the third call to do_cmd, $pid ends up
being expanded to the empty string before the loop executes on the
final machine.

I thought about double-escaping the dollar signs, but the
caller doesn't know how many levels of intermediate machines there are.
Is there a way to prevent the parameter expansion on the intermediate
machine, and only do it on the final machine?

Comment: What is `sersh`? If these were two `ssh` commands, I would recommend `ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh login1@host1" login2@host2 ...` in place of `ssh login1@host1 "ssh login@host2 ..."`, but I don't know if there's anything similar for `sersh`.

Comment: sersh is from the 'serio' (https://github.com/frowand/serio) tool.  It doesn't have any support for ProxyCommand.  However, what you suggest might work, because my use case is always using ssh to the first machine, and sersh to the second machine from there.  I'll try it out.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: The documentation for `ProxyCommand` (see `man ssh_config`) gives an example of `nc` as the command, so it may work; I just don't have any way to test or confirm it. (I think it expects the final host to still be running `sshd`, which won't be the case for your serial device, though.)

Answer (score 0):

[@MadPhysicist reminds me that I'd still have to escape the variable expansions. My answer is left here below for reference but @MadPhysicist is right: my answer probably fails to answer the question asked.]

Use `eval`.

Try this exercise, typing the following four commands at your shell's command line. I believe that the exercise is likely to answer your question.

```
$ X=55
$ A='echo $(( $X + $X ))'
$ echo "$A"
$ eval "$A"
```

Once the exercise has shown you what the shell's built-in command `eval` does, you can get the effect you want by using `eval` on the final machine in your chain.

[Please notice that the exercise says, `A='echo $(( $X + $X ))'`. It does not say, `` A=`echo $(( $X + $X ))` ``. Observe the way the quotation marks slant. You want ordinary single quotes here, not backticks.]

Comment: You'll still have to escape the variable expansions

Comment: Thanks.  This led me to a solution, I believe.  I put single-quotes around the final '$@' in the ssh2serial case, and it prevented it from expanding on the intermediate host:  ssh -i ${SSH_KEY} ${LOGIN}@{IPADDR} "sersh ${SER_LOGIN}@${SERIAL_DEV} '$@'".  I'm testing it with lots of different commands now.

Comment: Good. That `eval` can be useful sometimes, can't it? When you have some time, if you would either edit my answer in view of what you have discovered or post an answer of your own, that would help.

Comment: OK - your answer provides 2 tips, one about 'eval', which I didn't end up using, and the other about single quotes, which is what I ended up using, and which solved the problem nicely for me.  What is the best way forward?  I'd like to accept the answer, but note the portion that worked.  That is, I'd like to say that the single-quotes sufficed and 'eval' was not necessary.  Is this done more appropriately as an edit to your answer or a new answer.  (I've never edited someone else's answer before, so I don't know the propriety of that.)  Thanks.

Comment: A new answer would suffice. When you have time, just write the new answer and *accept* it. That should work.